# Should i make native or hybrid e-commerce app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, e-commerce, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building an webshop app for a company. As i am new to this I'm not sure which I should choose. I have seen alot of hybrid apps gaining popularity and performances are getting better. As I need to make the app for both Android and IOS i am very tempted to go with hybrid as it is much easier way of doing it. The app is gonna be webshop where customers can add items to their shopping cart/save it, come back later and so on.

So my main question is that if I should go with hybrid or just do it as native?

And if i go hybrid should I be aware of any problems or difficulties that might need me to completely rebuild the app as native? And where goes the line where I should definitely go for native?

And you can always give suggestions for any sdk-s or frameworks that i should consider.

That alot of questions and might be stupid but it's hard to find any good answers to these basic questions.

Thanks alot for any help you could give me on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **It depends**.

Based on what? Well, hybrid apps are great for **prototyping** and for a **short time to market** since, as you already mentioned, **you only need to write/maintain one code base**, which also reduces costs quite a bit. From my personal experience, **it's also easier to hire JavaScript developers** (if you're using React Native or Ionic) than both Android and iOS devs. On the performance side, as long as you don't try to do anything too resource-demanding (video/photo editing, heavy computation, etc.) you'll be fine. Moreover, **community has grown a lot for hybrid platforms** in the last few years so you can find posts and answers to most common problems easily. Finally, if you go for the hybrid approach you can almost always write a piece of native code and run it from your app (depending on the platform this can be more or less straightforward).

Now, on the downside **most hybrid solutions rely heavily on third-party libraries**, which can be well maintained... or not. It's not uncommon to find that some library you depend on for a core feature of your app doesn't support the latest version of the platform you are using, so you end up using an old version with all the problems that implies. Also, **getting them to work can give you some trouble** most of the times.

So, to sum up: if you are going for a *small, simple app with a small team and not many resources* the hybrid option is definitely the one you should go for. If you intend to add more *device-specific features* (camera, map, geolocation) and *have enough resources* then a native approach will save you a lot of headaches.

If you decide to go for a hybrid approach, there are many options out there: Ionic, React Native, Flutter... I believe there are already enough Medium posts comparing them, so be sure to give them a look. I've used RN and a bit of Ionic; RN has always worked well me, so I would suggest it but as I said I haven't really tried the others much.

Hope it helps!